# How do I prevent unity/nautilus from opening a new window when I insert an external hd?

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with unity. Every time I insert my external hard drive a new file manager window gets opened with the content of my drive. How do I prevent that window from being opened? 
I still want the drive to get mounted as usual, just not that it opens a new window.

(background: My external hd gets detected as a new mount every time I wake up from stand-by, and thus opens a new window each time. That in itself is due to a bug, but not one I can easily fix. Not opening a window should be possible, I guess?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 12.04 : System settings > Details > Removable Media > Never prompt or start programs on media insertion

Answer (score 0):

Try System-Settings->Removable Media if there is something set to "Open folder". This could cause your HDD to spawn a folder, if it holds some media files.